# Does AWS Lambda (C#) allow loading DLLs dynamically from a s3 bucket and instantiate it for use within a Lambda function?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, dynamic, dll, aws-lambda

My goal is to have a dynamic framework where i could externally build libraries (DLLs) and place them in an S3 bucket. At the required execution time the Lambda function must have some way to load the DLL from the s3 bucket and instantiate it. Does AWS with .NET core 2.0+ support this feature ? I did not find much documentation regarding the same.

Requesting for pointers please

Comment: Why wouldn't you package the dll with your lambda?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Does AWS with .NET core 2.0+

Yes. It's not actually related to AWS, you would do this in AWS Lambda the same way you would do it in any .NET Core application with "plugin-style" runtime DLL loading.

First, copy the required DLL from S3 to local disk. In AWS Lambda the only place you can write your DLL file is `/tmp`, but generally it is better to just call `System.IO.Path.GetTempPath()` instead of hard-coding paths.

```
var dllPath= Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "name-of-your.dll");
var request = new GetObjectRequest
{
    BucketName = "name-of-your-bucket",
    Key = "name-of-your-dll-in-S3"
};

using (var response = await S3.GetObjectAsync(request))
{
    await response.WriteResponseStreamToFileAsync(dllPath, false);
}
```

Or use `TransferUtility` if you prefer.

Now the tricky part. A lot has changed in .NET Core comparing to .NET 4+. Load the assembly:

```
var assembly = AssemblyLoadContext.GetLoadContext(typeof(ISomeInterface).GetTypeInfo().Assembly).LoadFromAssemblyPath(dllPath);
```

Obviously, your DLL should contain a class that implements `ISomeInterface`. Inside the assembly find the class that implements this interface. One way to do this:

```
var type = typeof(ISomeInterface);
var types = assembly.GetTypes().Where(t =>
                type.IsAssignableFrom(t) &&
                t.GetTypeInfo().IsClass &&
                !t.GetTypeInfo().IsAbstract);
var targetType = types.Single();
```

Create an instance of a class:

```
var instance = (ISomeInterface)Activator.CreateInstance(targetType);
```

And finally, use it as usual:

```
instance.SomeMethod();
```